# Relation between eigenvalues and the nullspace of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I am having trouble in understanding eigenvalues and eigenvectors correctly. In particular, why are the eigenvalues of a matrix related to the nullspace of $A-\lambda I$ ? What exactly does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if $Ax = \lambda x$, then $(A-\lambda I) x = Ax -\lambda x = \lambda x - \lambda x = 0$. This means that $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ for eigenvalue $\lambda$ **if and only if** it lies in the nullspace of $A-\lambda I$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lambda$ is eigenvalue of a matrix $A$  if and only if  exists a nonzero vctor $v$ such that $Av=\lambda v=\lambda Iv$ in the other words $(A-\lambda I)v=0 $ thus $A-\lambda I$ has nontrivial null space, Vice versa.